# Two floating divs, one text is vertical

Tags: html, css

Have been fiddling with this for an hour, starting to lose it. Basically I want something like this [image: Floating divs with vertical text]

I tried using CSS webkit-transform-rotate, but the vertical text will be out of place (also tried to set width & height but it seems to look weird)

Any help is more than appreciated!

Comment: can you post your current code?

Comment: Please can you add the code (CSS and HTML) you have already tried to the question.

Comment: [How to ask a **good** question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If the vertical text is not changeable then you can use image in place of that.

Comment: Unfortunately I already deleted my code as I gave up. I didn't want to use an image because the target audience are web devs so I wanted to keep it clean.

Comment: @jurasadam check the answer given below. That will do fine i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the trick for you. Check the code snippet.
you can use css transform for this. Just rotate the text -90 degrees and the problem is solved. Also add `writing-mode` as `tb-rl`.

```css
.test
  {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top:50px;
   
  }


  .vertical
  {
     writing-mode:tb-rl;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin:100 100;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 94px;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:38px
    
  }

  .normal
  {
    width: 190px;
    float: left;
    background:#555;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:-40px;
    padding:1px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="test">
 <div class="vertical">
  HELLO THERE
 </div>
 <div class="normal">
  some other content
      some other content
      some other content
      some other contentsome other content
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I did exactly that, but the left text is not aligned properly to the right text block, as you can see in your example too.

Comment: What exactly do you want? can you explain?

Comment: I want exactly the same result as in the image. Left side vertical text, aligned to be the same height as the right side text. The text is not dynamic so that's not a problem, you can fiddle with the font sizes, but it should look good on all screen sizes (using bootstrap).

Comment: Not 100% what I was looking for, but was helpful. Accepting it as an answer.